# In Jupyter Lab, how do I disable these suggestions when pressing tab?

Tags: python, settings, jupyter-lab, autosuggest

I just want to use tab to indent my comment. How do I do this? How do I disable these suggestions?

[image: Suggestions pop up whenever I press tab]

```
These are my current versions:
IPython          : 8.12.0
ipykernel        : 6.19.2
ipywidgets       : not installed
jupyter_client   : 8.1.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 1.23.4
jupyterlab       : 3.5.3
nbclient         : 0.5.13
nbconvert        : 6.5.4
nbformat         : 5.7.0
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.7.1
```

Can anyone help me?

I have tried to change to shortcut settings for completer, but it keeps "tab" for completion, whatever I do.

[image: Settings under "keyboard shortcuts"]

I have also changed the ipython config file, as suggested [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13451).

Comment: About, "I just want to use tab to indent my comment", did you try `SHIFT-Tab`?

Comment: If you select two or more characters or move cursor to beginning of the line it will indent your code. On the screenshot with shortcuts the `tab` is still set as a keybinding - did you click save?

Comment: @krassowski I only want to indent the comment, not the whole line. I have clicked save when changing the keybinding, but I feel like something is faulty with the buttons.

Comment: @Wayne I have tried SHIFT-Tab, as well as any other combination I could think of.

Comment: Regarding faulty buttons: you are running an older version of JupyterLab (latest is 4.0 and 3.6.x) - some bugs around these were fixed since. If you still see the issue in latest version please report the bug.

Comment: Regarding indenting comment only - I see, makes sense. I think some extra logic would be needed; would you like to open an enhancement request on https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues?